# How to define build-args in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
    node1:
            build: node1
            image: node1
            container_name: node1

    node2:
            build: node2
            image: node2
            container_name: node2
```

I can build both images and start them with a single command

`docker-compose up -d --build`

But I would like to use build-args on the builds. The original build script of the image outside of the scope of compose looks something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
docker build \
--build-arg ADMIN_USERNNAME_1=weblogic \
--build-arg ADMIN_PASSWORD_1=weblogic1 \
--build-arg ADMIN_NAME_1=admin \
--build-arg ...
--build-arg ... \
-t test/foo .
```

Both images would use build-args of the same name but different value. Also, as there are dozens of build args, it would be convenient to store them in a compose service specific build-properties file. Is this possible with docker-compose?

Comment: Warning for later people: for passwords, you might consider using a secret manager (Vault, k8s secrets, aws sms, docker swarm secrets) instead of a build arg to avoid security breaches. A build-time arg will bake the cred in the image, which means anyone with pull access can read it. Avoid using credentials at build-time.

Comment: Very important note about security, thanks a lot. Here is a solution: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/build-secrets-docker-compose/

Comment: @Bira I fail to see what this question has to do with AWS. The question doesn't mention it, and docker-compose is indeed an independent product.

Answer (score 197):

You can specify the arguments directly in your docker-compose file:

```
node1:
    build:
        context: node1
        args:
            ADMIN_USERNNAME: weblogic1
            ADMIN_PASSWORD: weblogic1
            ADMIN_NAME: admin1
    image: node1
    container_name: node1
```

See a full example: [MWE](https://gist.github.com/reitzig/4a1cccc965b50a15868fb345d770cdec)

The [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#args) (legacy v3 [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args)) have all detail.

Comment: For some reason `args` in the docker-compose file did not work for me when trying to use a shell var. Instead I had to use `--build-arg VARNAME=$VARNAME` when running the command.

Comment: @harvzor Not sure what you mean by that. Do you expect `docker-compose` to have excess to a Bash variable outside of its own runtime? Yeah, that won't work, and it shouldn't. You _can_ use environment variables, though: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: For multiline `--build-arg`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67135826/432903

Answer (score 55):

You can define your `args` with your build command of docker-compose.

Example
Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.13

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y \
    apache2-utils && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ARG username
ARG password

RUN htpasswd -bc /etc/nginx/.htpasswd $username $password
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node1:
     build: ./dir
```

The `./dir` contains the Dockerfile and I build with this command:

```
docker-compose build --build-arg username="my-user" --build-arg password="my-pass"
```

I see already:

```
Step 5/5 : RUN htpasswd -bc /etc/nginx/.htpasswd $username $password
 ---> Running in 80735195e35d
Adding password for user my-user
 ---> c52c92556825
```

I bring my stack up:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Now I can check inside the nginx container and my username and (encrypted) password are there:

```
docker@default:~/test$ docker exec -it test_node1_1 bash
root@208e4d75e2bd:/# cat /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
my-user:$apr1$qg4I/5RO$KMaOPvjbnKdZH37z2WYfe1
```

Using this method your able to pass `build args` to your `docker-compose` stack.

Comment: Environment variables can be used as you said, but they have to be defined in .env, not inside the compose file

Comment: This answer is very useful, it actually shows how `docker-compose` can be used with `--build-arg` on command-line, you can define your ARG in `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml` - **the :args array defined** and then finally override it on the command-line.

Comment: Seems correct, but for others, be wary of baking credentials into images like this. Username/password should be done at runtime, so your prod credentials don't show up in your repository

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, showing that `--build-arg` can be used with `docker-compose`

Answer (score 48):

In your `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG CERTBOT_TAG=latest
FROM certbot/certbot:${CERTBOT_TAG}
```

In your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
  certbot:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        CERTBOT_TAG: v0.40.1
```

And you can build or up your service:

```
docker-compose build certbot
```

Comment: I got an error using this format, 

`ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.certbot.build.args contains {"CERTBOT_TAG": "v0.40.1"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string`

My solution was to remove the `-` to turn it into a string instead of an object.

Comment: @heralight please fix the YAML syntax!

Answer (score 7):

As Salek mentioned above, adding `context: .` helps.

For example:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NODE_VERSION: 14.15.4
```

`

Answer (score 3):

**Docker File**

```
ARG ACCOUNT_ID

FROM $ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/my-composer:latest as composer
LABEL stage=intermediate
```

**Buildspec or CLI** execute the following command.

```
docker-compose build --build-arg ACCOUNT_ID="23423432423" --no-cache
```

**If you want to print the ACCOUNT_ID in CLI**

```
ARG ACCOUNT_ID

FROM amazonlinux:latest
RUN yum -y install aws-cli 
RUN echo $ACCOUNT_ID

FROM $ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/my-composer:latest as composer
LABEL stage=intermediate
```

Note: ARG should be on top of all `FROM` statement, then it will work as global ARG.