# How to pass multiline environment variable in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, logstash, opensearch

I am trying to convert this [docker run command](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/logstash/index/#:%7E:text=%2De%20%27input%20%7B%20stdin%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%20output%20%7B%0A%20%20%20opensearch%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20hosts%20%3D%3E%20%5B%22https%3A//opensearch%3A9200%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20index%20%3D%3E%20%22opensearch%2Dlogstash%2Ddocker%2D%25%7B%2BYYYY.MM.dd%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20user%20%3D%3E%20%22admin%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20password%20%3D%3E%20%22admin%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20ssl%20%3D%3E%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20ssl_certificate_verification%20%3D%3E%20false%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D%27):

```
docker run -it --rm --name logstash --net test opensearchproject/logstash-oss-with-opensearch-output-plugin:7.16.2 -e 'input { stdin { } } output {
 opensearch {
   hosts => ["https://opensearch:9200"]
   index => "opensearch-logstash-docker-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   user => "admin"
   password => "admin"
   ssl => true
   ssl_certificate_verification => false
   }
}'
```

to a docker-compose.yml file. However I can't  figure out how to define the environment config passed above. Any suggestions on how to pass nameless multiline environment variable to a docker-compose?

I tried multiple yaml multiline formats, but I keep getting:

> ERROR: environment variable name 'input { stdin { } } output { opensearch { hosts ' may not
> contain whitespace.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  logstash-producer:
    image: opensearchproject/logstash-oss-with-opensearch-output-plugin:7.16.2
    container_name: logstash-producer
    environment:
      - 'input { stdin { } } output {
          opensearch {
            hosts => ["https://opensearch:9200"]
            index => "opensearch-logstash-docker-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            user => "admin"
            password => "admin"
            ssl => true
            ssl_certificate_verification => false
          }
        }'
```

Comment: Could you post your docker compose yaml file?

Comment: The `-e ...` on your `docker run` command isn't setting an environment variable. It comes *after* the image name, so it's a command for the container.

Comment: @HansKilian can you suggest what's the replacement for it in docker-compose?

In the docker documentation -e specified environment variable https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#:~:text=%2D%2Denv%20%2C%20%2De,Set%20environment%20variables

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197806/how-to-get-proper-docker-compose-multiline-environment-variables-formatting . This question could be the possible duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `-e` bit comes after the image name, it's a command for the container.

I've never done this and I'm unable to test it, but try this

```
version: '3'

services:
  logstash-producer:
    image: opensearchproject/logstash-oss-with-opensearch-output-plugin:7.16.2
    container_name: logstash-producer
    command: |
        -e 'input { stdin { } } output {
        opensearch {
          hosts => ["https://opensearch:9200"]
          index => "opensearch-logstash-docker-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
          user => "admin"
          password => "admin"
          ssl => true
          ssl_certificate_verification => false
        }
      }'
```

If that doesn't work, I'd try putting the command all on one line.

Comment: This worked! I indented the command to line up with `|`