# How to use file to store the build args for a docker compose build command?

Tags: docker

I have come across [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54672432/80353) where the build args can be defined on the command itself or hardcoded in the yml itself.

I was wondering if there's another way, other than writing your own script that basically also calls the command with build args, so that the build args values are in a separate file.

Comment: you can use file for run time env `env_file: variables.env`

Comment: @Adiii I have tried that before but docker compose somehow cannot use that for build args. As env variables when running containers yes.