# Passing env variables to RUN in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, arguments

How to pass environment variables to `RUN` command in Dockerfile? In my scenario, I want to pass env variables to `RUN` command which runs a script & uses these variables?

`.env`

```bash
NAME=John
```

`script.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo $NAME
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:3.14

COPY . .

RUN chmod +x script.sh

RUN ./script.sh
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.1"

services:
  foo:
    container_name: foo
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
```

How can I pass the `NAME` env variable to the last `RUN` command in Dockerfile (to be used by the `script` executable)?

I am aware of `--build-arg` but it is inconvenient when there are 100s of env variables. Even then how can I format the `docker compose` command to read all arguments from an env file & pass them as build arguments?

Comment: version: 3.1? Really?.. If you're writing new docker system, consider upgrading to latest (3.9 as of now).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define build-args in docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50734271/how-to-define-build-args-in-docker-compose)